# Plugin JS para criar apresentações com gráficos

Tags: javascript, plugin, slide

Estou precisando desenvolver uma página de monitoramento onde irá ter gráficos para apresentar informações em forma de slide, ou seja, praticamente seria um "*carousel*" pegando a tela inteira, onde cada *slide* teria um gráfico diferente.

Alguém conhece um plugin js pra fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei um ótimo framework para criar apresentações em Javascript, é fácil de entender e simples de desenvolver.
Ele se chama [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js) e possui integração com o [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/), que no meu caso foi muito útil para desenvolver gráficos durante a apresentação.

Aqui está uma demo para quem quiser ver em prática os slides desse framework.

Demo: https://revealjs.com/#/

Comment: Google Charts também é uma opção

Comment: Com certeza, no meu caso utilizei Chart.js pois atendeu no que eu precisava, mas creio que funcionaria com Google Charts também.